# Cutting a 7-by-9 rectangle

Tags: mathematics, geometry, dissection, tiling

Is it possible to dissect a $7\times9$ rectangle into $21$ pieces that are $L$-shaped and that consist of three little squares?

Comment: I suspect the answer is no; now I just need to find the invariant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer blatantly stolen from [this Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1580996/256930):

> [image: tiling]

Comment: Makes me wonder where OP got the question from in the first place.